# (XSetWindowBackground) how to convert "RGB" <-> "unsigned long"

Tags: xlib

I want to set the background of a window with color, but [XSetWindowBackground](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XSetWindowBackground.html) has an unisgned long to set the color, how can I link an unsigned long for a rgb value ?

Comment: You may want to look at `XAllocColor` and friends.

Comment: What is your starting point, separate integer r g and b values or a string e.g. "#112233"?

Comment: rgb or hex are fine both, I know how to convert a hex value to rgb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have RGB values as integers then you can use XAllocColor with an XColor structure as follows:

```
  XColor col;
  col.red = 65535;  // value is 0-65535
  col.green = 32767;
  col.blue = 0;
  XAllocColor(dis, DefaultColormap(display,0), &col);
```

the value you want is in

```
col.pixel
```

if you have a hex string then you convert it to an XColor with:

```
 XParseColor(display, DefaultColormap(display,0), "#FF7F00", &col);;
```